# Can't update Meteor application to 1.2 without breaking

Tags: cordova, meteor, updates, babeljs, package.json

Trying to update my application (the highest I can get to is 1.1) anything higher and I get:

```
    => Started proxy.                             
    => Started MongoDB.                           
    => Errors prevented startup:                  

   While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):
   native: /Users/Archie/package.json: Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected end
   of input
   at Object.parse (native)
   at OptionManager.addConfig
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:100:62)
   at OptionManager.findConfigs
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:171:32)
   at OptionManager.init
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:229:12)
   at File.initOptions
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:147:75)
   at new File
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:137:22)
   at Pipeline.transform
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:164:16)
   at
   /Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:26:18
   at Cache.Cp.get
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/cache.js:89:19)
   at Object.compile
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:20:23)
   at Object.Babel.compile (packages/babel-compiler/babel.js:42:1)
   at packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:58:1
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at BabelCompiler.BCp.processFilesForTarget
   (packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:17:1)


   While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.cordova):
   native: /Users/Archie/package.json: Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected end
   of input
   at Object.parse (native)
   at OptionManager.addConfig
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:100:62)
   at OptionManager.findConfigs
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:171:32)
   at OptionManager.init
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:229:12)
   at File.initOptions
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:147:75)
   at new File
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:137:22)
   at Pipeline.transform
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:164:16)
   at
   /Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:26:18
   at Cache.Cp.get
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/cache.js:89:19)
   at Object.compile
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:20:23)
   at Object.Babel.compile (packages/babel-compiler/babel.js:42:1)
   at packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:58:1
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at BabelCompiler.BCp.processFilesForTarget
   (packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:17:1)


   While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.osx.x86_64):
   native: /Users/Archie/package.json: Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected end
   of input
   at Object.parse (native)
   at OptionManager.addConfig
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:100:62)
   at OptionManager.findConfigs
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:171:32)
   at OptionManager.init
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:229:12)
   at File.initOptions
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:147:75)
   at new File
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:137:22)
   at Pipeline.transform
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:164:16)
   at
   /Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:26:18
   at Cache.Cp.get
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/cache.js:89:19)
   at Object.compile
   (/Users/Archie/.meteor/packages/ecmascript/.0.1.3.11anxi0++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compile-ecmascript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/index.js:20:23)
   at Object.Babel.compile (packages/babel-compiler/babel.js:42:1)
   at packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:58:1
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at BabelCompiler.BCp.processFilesForTarget
   (packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:17:1)
```

The current (broken) version is at Meteor 1.2

The package.json at is indeed blank. Not sure why it is referencing it though as I've never had to use a JSON file at /Users/Archie/package.json for the previous versions.

Very unsure how to tackle this or how to get my app updated! I've tried things like reinstalling Meteor or updating to a higher version but with no luck.

I have had other Meteor apps update to 1.4 without issue on this same desktop so unsure why there is such a problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let try put an empty JSON object, e.g. `{}`, in the `package.json` file which you are having problem with

Comment: I am puzzled why it is referring to /Users/Archie/package.json, which is in your home directory, when presumably your meteor project lives somewhere else. You could try a `meteor reset` and/or `rm -rf .meteor/local`  which might help

Comment: @Mikkel This is also what puzzles me! `meteor reset` and `rm -rf .meteor/local` do nothing unfortunately but thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @Khang this seemed to fix it! Somewhat bizarrely. Now I'm left with Iron Router being broken with this error:

`Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Home', {
    data: function () { return Items.findOne({_id: this.params._id}); }
  });
});`

But I guess this is another problem entirely that stems from the update!